# How to use capture groups with sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace some text in a file using `sed` but I'm having troubles.

`sed -ir 's/(\$hello = )true/\1false/' /path/to/my/file.txt` gives the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS`.

I want to replace `$hello = true` with `$hello = false`, so in order to avoid typing `$hello =` twice I wanted to use capture groups - which isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: You don't have to escape parentheses in extended regex mode, if it was your intent with the `r` into `-ir`, but actually if you want both options `-i` and `-r` then you have to keep them apart or use `-ri` instead of `-ir` because the latter interprets the part after `-i` as an optional backup suffix.

Comment: @luciole75w thank you, that solved it! If you'd like to write an answer, I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to escape parentheses in extended regex mode, if it was your intent with the `r` into `-ir`, but actually if you want both options `-i` and `-r` then you have to keep them apart or use `-ri` instead of `-ir` because the latter interprets the part after `-i` as an optional backup suffix.

From [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002di)

> Because -i takes an optional argument, it should
>     not be followed by other short options:
>
> `sed -Ei '...' FILE`
>
> Same as -E -i with no backup suffix - FILE will be edited in-place without creating a backup.
>
> `sed -iE '...' FILE`
>
> This is equivalent to --in-place=E, creating FILEE as backup
>     of FILE

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the parenthesis with backslashes `\(...\)`, to be used as grouping.

See [THE SED FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/sedfaq.txt), section "3.1.2. Escape characters on the right side of "s///"" has an example:

> 3.1.2. Escape characters on the right side of "s///"
>
> The right-hand side (the replacement part) in "s/find/replace/" is
>      almost always a string literal, with no interpolation of these
>      metacharacters:
>
> ```
>   .   ^   $   [   ]   {   }   (   )  ?   +   *   |
> ```
>
> Three things *are* interpolated: ampersand (&), backreferences, and
>      options for special seds. An ampersand on the RHS is replaced by
>      the entire expression matched on the LHS. There is *never* any
>      reason to use grouping like this:
>
> ```
>   s/\(some-complex-regex\)/one two \1 three/
> ```

And later in section "F. GNU sed v2.05 and higher versions":

> F. GNU sed v2.05 and higher versions
>
> ...
>
> Undocumented -r switch:
>
> Beginning with version 3.02, GNU sed has an undocumented -r switch
>      (undocumented till version 4.0), activating Extended Regular
>      Expressions in the following manner:
>
> ```
>  ?      -  0 or 1 occurrence of previous character
>  +      -  1 or more occurrences of previous character
>  |      -  matches the string on either side, e.g., foo|bar
>  (...)  -  enable grouping without backslash
>  {...}  -  enable interval expression without backslash
> ```
>
> When the -r switch (mnemonic: "regular expression") is used, prefix
>      these symbols with a backslash to disable the special meaning.

---

For documentation of regular expression syntax used in (GNU) sed, see [Overview of basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html)

> #### 5.3 Overview of basic regular expression syntax
>
> ...
>
> **\(regexp\)**
>
> Groups the inner regexp as a whole, this is used to:
>
> - Apply postfix operators, like (abcd)*: this will search for zero or more whole sequences of ‘abcd’, while abcd* would search for ‘abc’ followed by zero or more occurrences of ‘d’. Note that support for (abcd)* is required by POSIX 1003.1-2001, but many non-GNU implementations do not support it and hence it is not universally portable.
> - Use back references (see below).